# PayPal REST API returning error code 500 for payment verification

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I have a problem with the Paypal REST API and the verification of a mobile (Android) payment.
Tried to follow this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
There are 5 different steps to reach verification:

1. Your app makes a successful payment with a PayPal Mobile SDK.
2. Your app sends data about the payment to your server
3. Your server can store the payment id value in a database.
4. From your server, use the payment id value to look up the payment
   details with the REST API.
5. You verify the payment details, as described below.

Now I am stuck at point 4.
I have no problem getting the access token from "api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token" but when I am trying to look up the payment with "api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/" I get an HTTP response code: 500.

```
private static String getPaymentVerification(String paymentId,
            String accessToken) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Verify Payment.");
            URL url = new URL("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/"+ paymentId);
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
            uc.setDoOutput(true);
            uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            InputStream is = uc.getInputStream();
```

This is the code of the method till exception occurs.
I am using mobile Paypal SDK 2.3.3.

Comment: If you provide the entire 500 response contents, PayPal will be able to debug easier.  Sometimes the PayPal sandbox has timeout issues, but it should be rare enough such that a retry will get you the right result.

Comment: The exception details are the following: "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXX..."